# iOS Application Updating - Is it possible to do partial update of .app?

Tags: ios, packaging, ipa

I have an iPad application that during beta testing may need a small code update here and there, but has a large number of graphics assets (300MB+).

Is there a way of creating a partial .ipa file that just has the changes instead of re-installing the whole application along with graphics files each time?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: NO!

Explanation:

Apple gives you no means to do so !!!

The .ipa is just a .zip file. So it seems on the first look, that you can do it.

But there are 2 problems

1. You need direct access to the iOs Devices. You normally don't have it for your Beta-Tester.
2. You will need to sign your code again. This you can only do on your local machine, because you need your private key for the task

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are thinking of would be considered a "patch". Apple forces you to update the entire app bundle. Take the Tomtom app for example. The app is right around 1.5GB's so for small minor changes they would need to reupload the entire 1.5GB bundle.

Comment: Yes I guessed so. Its a bit of a stinker! Workaround suggestions?

Comment: I agree. What I have done in the past is if there is a feature I can control / update remotely, I would go that route so you don't have to upload such a large package or wait for the review process.

Answer (score 0):

For the App Store builds, things have changed since iOS6 and iOS 7.1:

> Starting with iOS 6, the app store will automatically produce an update package for all new versions of apps submitted to the store. When generating the update package, the app store compares one or more prior versions of your app to the new version and creates an optimized package for each that contains only the content that has changed between versions of your app, excluding any content that did not change. This comparison looks at everything in the application bundle, including the application executable, nibs, localizations, image files, video files, audio files, text files, and files containing data in a custom format.
>
> For devices running iOS 6.x and iOS 7.0, the update package will include any file, in its entirety, that has changed in the new version of the app. For example, if you have a 10 MB file in your app and only change 1 KB of content within that file in the new version of the app, the update package for that new version will contain the full 10 MB file.
>
> For devices running iOS 7.1 and later, the update package may include only the differences between the old and new versions of a changed file instead of the full file. This may significantly reduce the size of the update package in the case where only a small part of a large file changes, but will increase the update's installation time on the device. For this reason, the two tips above are still important even for updates on iOS 7.1 and later. Minimizing changed content and localizing it to many smaller files instead of one larger monolithic file will reduce the download size in all cases and will speed up installation on devices running iOS 7.1 and later.

Source: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1779/_index.html